# Force dpkg repair

Tags: debian, apt, python, dpkg

I did a terrible mistake and deleted two folders from the `/usr/lib` directory on my Debian. I deleted `python2.7/` and `pkgconfig/`

Things I've tried to fix it without success:

- `sudo dpkg -i python2*`
  -> *"could not find platform independent libraries"* --> *"/usr/lib/pyton2.7/py_compile.py no such file"*
- even deleting it (python; for future reinstalling) via
  `sudo dpkg -i python2.7-minimal` --> cant remove because *python2.7-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>=... .deb) and python2.7 depends on python2.7-minimal (>=..._rc2.deb)*

So I cant reinstall it or repair the packages as long they are not "configured" by dpkg as a `apt-get install python` says but also cant remove them for a clean reinstall since their are dependencies on different version in dpkg and I dont know how to solve this.

So how can I completely remove a packages with all dependencies via dpkg or apt to solve the described situation from above?

Answer (score 1):

If `apt` is borked, sometimes it's possible to set things right manually with `dpkg` and the full path of the local cached package.  Here's how:

1. `cd` to where `apt` stores the packages, namely */var/cache/apt/archives/*
2. `dpkg` then (*as needed*) the switch for install, remove, purge or whatnot, then the *filename* of the package in the current directory.  So to install one of several versions of *'foobar'* that were successively installed recently, type `dpkg -i foobar<TAB>` and the '' key will fill in the rest with `bash` autocompletion, or show the available versions.
3. If `dpkg` says you need *'fizban'*, (or must get rid of *'fizban'*), do step #2, with *'fizban'*.  Then try step #2 with *'foobar'* again.
4. Repeat #2 & #3 until the system is in the desired state.

That assumes the package archives needed are still cached locally.  Sometimes the packages need to be hunted down online.  In which case the version number of the needed package might be somewhat *uncertain* -- in such cases, `/var/log/dpkg.log` has the answer, just `grep` or `sed` through that for the package name, and it'll show the versions `dpkg` has worked with so far.